# Compiler warning at std::vector push_back of an int with warning level 3

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-warnings

I am using the intel c++ compiler icc version 18.0.3.

If I compile the [following code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G3ymf6) with `-w3`

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(2);
    return 0;
}
```

> test_w3.cpp(6): remark #383: value copied to temporary, reference to
>   temporary used
>         vec.push_back(2);

[Replacing](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4hnroq) the `2` with a const variable as

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    const int a = 2;
    vec.push_back(a);
    return 0;
}
```

does not give a warning.

What does this warning mean? Can it safely be ignored (although warning free code is desirable)?

Comment: Does it give same remark if vector is declared outside of main function or if you print result?

Comment: If I print it the remark is still given. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/atlYe6

Comment: accoridng to this post [intel-c-compiler/topic/300453](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/300453). The remark is unimportant and by the sounds of it, should of been removed, it might be a bug.

Comment: If I move to a function the remark is also still given. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fKoED3

Comment: It really looks like a mistaken warning. Even icc doesn't complain about the same code if you replace `-w3` with `-Wall`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intel has a site for exactly this issue with exactly your problem [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cdiag383). It is from 2008, but seems to be applicable to your problem. **The warning exists, as this programming style may lead to hidden temporary objects and can be ignored in some cases**.

They state for this example:

```
void foo(const int &var)
{
}

void foobar()
{
    std::vector<std::string> numlist
        // 383 remark here: a tempory object with "123" is created
        numlist.push_back("123");       
    foo(10);       // gives 383

}
```

The following:

> **Resolution:**
>
> - Provide a proper object for initializing the reference.
> - Can safely ignore this warning for pushback function of vector. The vector copies the argument into its own storage; it never stores the original argument. Therefore, using a temporary is perfectly safe.

So you may ignore the warning, even though this contradicts the general rule **never ignore warnings**.

In my opinion Intel has chosen a bad way, as warnings which result from misdiagnosis hinder development.

Comment: Ignoring warnings is unfortunately a pretty bad idea since this means that *real* warnings will drown in the false-positive noise. That’s why such warnings (which are likely to be false-positives) are a bad idea to begin with. This is a bad warning. It should be disabled globally in the command-line options.

Comment: I completely agree

Comment: @KonradRudolph Added a warning about ignoring warnings! Thanks for you suggestion!

Comment: Shouldn't one use `emplace_back()` here anyway, in reality? ICC should not warn for that (I don't know if it *does*, but it *shouldn't*). My PoV is only to use `push` methods to copy/move an existing instance (i.e. not a temporary), but if creating a new element from ctor args, they should be forwarded by `emplace` rather than using a temporary as a vehicle. To me, that both states intent more clearly and can avoid wasteful copies/moves - and, I learned today, warnings!

Comment: @underscore_d neither push_back nor emplace_back should emit a warning, but they do (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1BDtLX for an emplace_back example).

Comment: @underscore_d Sorry, missunderstood your comment. Yes emplace_back would create the integer in place. But for the sample provided this is not going to make any difference ;)